# export higher component wrapper syntax invalid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
import asyncComponent from './asyncComponent'

const AsyncButton = asyncComponent(() => import('./Buttons'))
    export { ButtonPrimary } = AsyncButton
```

Why above code is not valid? `Button` component is a ordinary component.

I do this `export { ButtonPrimary } from './Buttons'` it's fine.

Mt asyncComponent code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

    const asyncComponent = importComponent => {
      class AsyncComponent extends Component {
        state = {
          component: null
        }

        async componentDidMount() {
          const { default: component } = await importComponent()

          this.setState({
            component: component
          })
        }

        render() {
          const C = this.state.component

          return C ? <C {...this.props} /> : null
        }
      }

      return AsyncComponent
    }

    export default asyncComponent
```

Comment: FYI, you may want to consider using an existing solution like https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable

Comment: I have no idea what you expect `export { ButtonPrimary } = AsyncButton` to do. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like

```
const AsyncButton = asyncComponent(() => import('./Buttons'))
export { ButtonPrimary } = AsyncButton
```

should be

```
export const ButtonPrimary = asyncComponent(() => import('./Buttons'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`export { ButtonPrimary } = AsyncButton` syntax is invalid because `export` supports [a limited set of syntax variations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export). It doesn't do destructuring, also `ButtonPrimary` isn't `AsyncButton` property.

If `ButtonPrimary` is `Buttons` module export:

```
export { ButtonPrimary } from './Buttons';
```

Then it should be:

```
const AsyncButton = asyncComponent(async () => (await import('./Buttons')).ButtonPrimary);
export { AsyncButton as ButtonPrimary };
```